# Safari submitting form when item from select field is chosen rather then submit button

Tags: html, forms, safari, submit, osx-lion

I built an internal project management system for our office. The system has functioned fine for the last year. After upgrading to Lion and Safari 5 I have been experiencing some submit issues. The form has several select list and when a user tries to select an option from the list it kicks them out of the application or tries to submit the form. Has anyone else experience this? Here is the code on my select button.

I am using this jQuery Validation Plugin found Here:

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8.1/jquery.validate.js

```
<fieldset style="float:left; margin-right:20px;">
   <label><b>*Will this Project Have Out of House Fees?</b></label>
   <select name="outofhouse" id="outofhouse" class="required">
          <option value="">Your Answer is?</option>
          <option value="1">No</option>
          <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
          <option value="TBD">TBD</option>
   </select></fieldset>

<!-- the JS -->

      <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#add_project").validate({
  rules: {
amount: {
required: true,
}
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think that can happen without some javascript involved. I'm guessing that `class="required"` means that the select is being checked by a validator, and that validator is somehow submitting the form by accident. Can you post any javascript that might match that description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experiencing the same problem. According to this solution over here it has nothing to do with the validate plugin but with webfonts and/or a border being set (or set to 0) on the select element:

http://redrata.com/2011/07/safari-woff-select-field-crash/

For me removing all border settings on the select element did the trick.